# C#: String variable only contains substring of what is output in Console.Write

Tags: c#, marshalling

So, here's the thing. I'm printing a string from

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    public UInt32 dwStructSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public String lpszSourceUrlName;
    ...
}

...

while(...) 
{   
    INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO entry;
    ...
    String url = entry.lpszSourceUrlName;
    Console.WriteLine(url);
}
```

The thing is, with `Console.WriteLine()`, I get lines like `Visited:lilymu@file:///C:/Users/lilymu/Desktop/scriptoutput.txt` but when I run the debugger and check the value of `url`, I get `file:///C:/Users/lilymu/Desktop/scriptoutput.txt`, which is the truncated version.

Why? I'm suspecting that it could have been the marshalling that was not done properly, but it would be great if anyone could explain why this is happening, and how to resolve this.

Comment: When you say "when I run the debugger and check the value", which value are you checking? Are you hovering over the `entry` variable? Or are you looking at the value being stored in `url`?

Comment: @ryancdotnet Yea, I should have been more clear - edited for clarity.